# Network on MainThread Exception (One app is working, other one throwing exception)

Tags: java, android, tcp, networkonmainthread

I am having an awkward issue (may be for me). I am using the timer to perform Tcp listner and socket programming. I am opening a socket to listen any data present on the port sent from another Android device (working correctly) regularly. I have created 2 applications to test the data receiving, one is just dummy and second is my main application. I am getting exception in my main application but not in the dummy application.

Exception is : `android.os.NetworkonMainThreadException`

The code is exactly same in both apps here it is

`onCreate()` contains

```
timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {           
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
```

`TimerMethod()` is as follows

```
private void TimerMethod()
    {
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }
```

`Timer_Tick` is:

```
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                runTcpServer();
            }

            catch(Exception a)
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText(a.toString());
            }

        }
    };
```

And the main Tcp method to listen the data on the port

```
public void runTcpServer()
    {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(TCP_SERVER_PORT);
            //ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
            //accept connections
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //receive a message
            String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");

            TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            //Log.d("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
            tv.append(incomingMsg);
            //send a message
            String outgoingMsg = "goodbye from port " + TCP_SERVER_PORT + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            out.write(outgoingMsg);
            out.flush();
            Log.d("TcpServer", "sent: " + outgoingMsg);
            //textDisplay.append("sent: " + outgoingMsg);

            //SystemClock.sleep(5000);
            s.close();
        } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
            //if timeout occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Error",e.toString());
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

The exception i am getting is when i am calling the `runTcpServer()` in `Timer_Tick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running network related operation on the main ui thread. You should use Asynctask or create a new thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Check the above link

I suggest you use asynctask.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Use Asynctask and move your `runTcpServer()`. Also remember you cannot update ui from a background thread. You will have to use `runOnUiThread` or update ui in `onPostExecute`

Move all your network related operation to doInbackground().  Move the below to onPostExecute(). You can return the result of computation in doInbackground(). Based on the result update ui in onPostExecute

```
    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //Log.d("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
    tv.append(incomingMsg);
```

Comment: Why it is running in the dummy application created for just testing ? the data received is correct.

Comment: What you mean by dummy application created?

Comment: A test app with same procedure as mentioned above is working correctly.

Comment: did you test it on a real device and on what version check the first link

Comment: also why do you require a timer?

Comment: Yes tested on the real device. Its minsdk target is 4 (the one working).

Comment: Need timer to keep running the tcp server to check the data on the port

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. pls check the first link in the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the error

```
   this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
```

Never run network task in UI thread(Main thread)!

Or use this to enable network task in UI thread, but it is not fair

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Why it is running in the dummy application created for just testing ?

Comment: Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI. The AsyncTask class provides one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.

Comment: to enable network task in UI thread See edit

Answer (score 1):

The error is visible you are executing timer on UI Thread `this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);`, Network operation should always be performed on Worker Thread,   instead just do new `Thread(new Timer_Tick()).start();`, executing network operation(as they are long running process) cause UI to not respond till network operation is complete.

**Addition**
I saw this is android question, You can use AsyncTask See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html After Android OS 2.3 Network Operation on UI thread is not allowed